# which of these linq queries are more performant?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Which is the better way to carry out this search:

```
context.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParameterName == "SomeValue").ParameterValue
```

or

```
context.Parameters.Where(x => x.ParameterName == "SomeValue").FirstOrDefault().ParameterValue
```

Does it matter *at all*?

Comment: There is no difference. Be careful with `FirstOrDefault().ParameterValue`, if you get `null` you will get an exception when trying to access `ParameterValue`.

Comment: I'd say that they compile to the very same SQL

Comment: Its a duplicate question you might find the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059285/c-sharp-linq-whereexpression-firstordefault-vs-firstordefaultexpression)